# How to find public IP of your android device

Tags: android

As the question says I would like to know how to find public IP address of my android device programatically in code.

I have seen some old outdated answers with getting local IP address, but I need a public one

Comment: Your Android device only has a public ip address if it is on mobile connection. Not on wifi. What would you do with such an ip address if you knew it?

Comment: I think you are wrong. On wifi it also has public IP address

Comment: No. With wifi the used router has a public ip address. The phone only a local then.

Comment: Yes but you can still get the public ip address of router. Now ther router's public IP is equal to android device's public IP since It represents device's public IP

Comment: use HTTP GET api.ipify.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reliable way to determine public ip address of the used router is to connect to someone on the internet.

For instance to https://www.whatismyip.com

You will get a html page where you can parse that ip out.

There exists sites which only return an ip so that would be enough and easier.

At the moment i have no further urls.

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what to do next

Answer (score 1):

Allows you to obtain the IP address of the device used.

```
private String getIpAddress() {
        String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
                    .getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
                        .nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
                        .getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();
    
                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += inetAddress.getHostAddress();
                    }
    
                }
    
            }
    
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
        }
    
        return ip;
    }
```

Comment: No sir, this is not PUBLIC IP address. you are getting my local IP address.
I need a public IP